# DrawerLayout without scrolling, fixed height

Tags: android, scroll, drawerlayout

In my app I use DrawerLayout for lateral menu. In this menu I have a header, 6 rows in ListView and a image footer. This is my lateral menu and I would like that it would have a fixed height (fill_parent) because it never changes and I don't want scrolling in this menu, how can I do it?

This is my DrawerLayout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/backgr_greysoft" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/listDrawer_width"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/backgr_greysoft"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="@color/navdrw_grey" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I want the same aspect for all smartphones, I don't want scrolling in some cases and not scrolling in other cases that the smartphone is bigger.

EDIT:

> //DRAWERLAYOUT

```
    navDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    //Lista
    navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
    //Declaramos el header de Navigation Drawer
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.search, null);
    //Establecemos el header
    navList.addHeaderView(header);
    //Declaramos el pie de Navigation Drawer
    View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.navfooter, null);
    //Establecemos el pie
    navList.addFooterView(footer);
    //Tomamos listado de imágenes desde drawable
    navIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.navigation_iconos);
    //Tomamos listado de títulos desde el string-array de los recursos
    titulos = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_options);
    //Listado de títulos de barra de navegación
    navItems = new ArrayList<Navigation_Item>();
    //Agregamos objetos Navigation_Item al array
    //ESCANER
    navItems.add(new Navigation_Item(titulos[0], navIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    //DESCARGAS
    navItems.add(new Navigation_Item(titulos[1], navIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    //FOTOGRAFÍAS
    navItems.add(new Navigation_Item(titulos[2], navIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    //FAVORITOS
    navItems.add(new Navigation_Item(titulos[3], navIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    //CONFIGURACIÓN
    navItems.add(new Navigation_Item(titulos[4], navIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    //COMPARTIR APLICACIÓN
    navItems.add(new Navigation_Item(titulos[5], navIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
    //Declaramos y seteamos el adaptador al cual le pasamos el array con los títulos
    navAdapter = new NavigationAdapter(this, navItems);
    navList.setAdapter(navAdapter);
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use a vertical `LinearLayout` instead of a `ListView`. Lists have implicit scrolling as they might display multiple items.

```
<LinearLayout>
    <Button1>
    <Button2>
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

---

EDIT:

Try this layout (adapt your code conveniently):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/backgr_greysoft" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lista"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/navdrw_grey"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/backgr_greysoft"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

        <!-- FOOTER: ADD THE REST OF FOOTER ITEMS INSIDE IT (or replace container by a view if you only need that view as footer: a TextView for instance) -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Footer" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: But @Juanjo Vega, how you put the header, 6 buttons and the footer?? I already have set all functions of the class with navigationDrawer, will I able to keep using the same way?

Comment: Is there any way to put not scrolling in ListView? I have tried to use LinearLayout with Buttons but I have to change all functions of my main class because there is no ListView now =O

Comment: ListView won't scroll if items fit in the visible space. Otherwise it will scroll to allow interaction with all the items in it.

Comment: yes ok, but if I add a footer at the end of the listView in some Android devices it can not be seen and I have to do scroll ... I want to see always all items in screen, not scrolling in DrawerLayout ... how can I do it?

Comment: I already told you: instead of placing your items in a ListView, use a vertical layout and place your buttons there. In my opinion is not a good idea, I'd rather use a list with options and the footer out of the list, at bottom, so it will be always visible. I have an app where I add items to drawer through a button. The button is at the top of it while the listview fills the rest of the space, so the button is always visible, but I can scroll through items.

Comment: that is! How I put the footer out he list, at bottom in DrawerLayout?? I want that footer is always visible, but I have tried to put in Drawerlayout a <LINEARLAYOUT orientation=vertical <ListView weight=0.9/> <ImageView weight=0.1/> </LINEARLAYOUT> ... but I get next mistake: "Cannot cast LinearLayout params to DrawerLayout params" ... how can I do it? Thanks for your help! xD

Comment: thanks for your answer but, this does not work! I get next mistake: "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams"